# Rental income: What distinguishes co-ownership from partnership?

Tags: canada, canada-revenue-agency

I own a condo unit with siblings, which we rent out.  The unit was purchased for eventual habitation by parents, when they are older and need to be close.  We are still paying mortgage on it.

Canada Revenue Agency's (CRA's) T776 form for rental income distinguishes between co-ownership of a rental unit versus a partnership.  I haven't found a non-expert explanation of the distinction.  CRA's [Ownership](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/businesses/topics/rental-income/ownership.html) page says some things about partnerships, but those things seem to apply to ownership as well.  Nowhere is it explicit about the general idea behind the distinction.

The webpage also cites a much more technical document [Income Tax Folio S4-F16-C1, What is a Partnership?](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/technical-information/income-tax/income-tax-folios-index/series-4-businesses/series-4-businesses-folio-16-partnerships/income-tax-folio-s4-f16-c1-what-a-partnership.html), but I don't find it helpful at all.

I'm not looking for a technically defensible definition.  Just the guiding idea of why the distinction is even made.

Comment: I think that's a legal question, and would probably get better answers in the law section of Stack Exchange than here.

Comment: OK, thanks.  Since I'm only looking for the motivating idea rather than the technical definition, I'd like to wait a while and see if anyone can chime in.  I have a phobia of legal technicalities.

Comment: The definition seems to depend on the province, CRA doesn't define what it is.

Comment: I suspect -- but have no evidence -- that the difference is one of whether there's a contract explicitly defining percentage ownership, rights and responsibilities of each of the parties. and that sort of thing.

Comment: @littlelady: I was hoping for the motivating idea rather than a legal definition.  There must be some kind of intent behind such distinction.

Comment: @keshlam: Huh.  OK, so it's the level of formalization (possibly).

Comment: @user2153235 one reason for the distinction is that co-ownership implies partnership, but partnership doesn't necessarily imply co-ownership

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distinction is made to accommodate the realities. As far as I can search and understand, I find there are different partnership laws in different provinces. In some provinces, this co-ownership might be treated as a partnership and in some, not. People choose to create partnerships for their benefit over just co-ownership like limited liability.

Comment: Thanks, Manish.  I've marked this as the answer, but it's an answer in that it presents possibilities that make sense.  Plausibilities.

Comment: You're welcome. Like there could be partnership firms where the business of buying and renting properties is done. The element of "business" is the only criterion which distinguishes the co-ownership and partnership.

Comment: And profit sharing also.